# Anyone follow this highly-available-mysql-cluster guide witch success?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture, drbd

I am following this guide [[Deploying a highly available MySQL 5.6 cluster with DRBD on Compute Engine]](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-highly-available-mysql-cluster-with-drbd-on-compute-engine#starting_the_cluster)[2](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-highly-available-mysql-cluster-with-drbd-on-compute-engine#costs)

Although the guide is written for ubuntu-1604-lts, the GCP doesn't have any the image more (I think), so I changed it to ubuntu-1804-lts to continues the guide.

At the same time, I ran the Verify the status of DRBD: command as

```
sudo cat /proc/drbd | grep ============
```

It never return the output from the guide, which is:

```
[===================>] sync'ed:100.0% (208/307188)M
```

Since there is not nothing retuned, but when we cat the file(cat /proc/drbd), we get:

```
version: 8.4.7 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: F7D2F0C9036CD0E796D5958
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:0 nr:6206288 dw:320880044 dr:0 al:8 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

Any point to find a updated guide or fix the issue of `"status of DRBD:"` Thank you.

Comment: Menu > Compute engine > images > show deprecated images (ubuntu-1604-lts family is still available). Filter with "ubuntu-1604"

Comment: @danyL Can you please show me how you use filter "ubuntu-1604" ?
replacing  --image-family=ubuntu-1604-lts   to --image-family=ubuntu-1604 doesn't help  
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/zones/asia-east1-c/imageFamilyViews/ubuntu-1604' was not found

Comment: just put ubuntu-1604 n hit enter

Comment: That is what I did, but it gives this error. 
(gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource: - The resource 'projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/zones/asia-east1-c/imageFamilyViews/ubuntu-1604' was not found

Comment: I was able to create one.

Comment: Since the screenshot i linked is not helpful, I will delete it, and hopefully a community member will put a better answer.

Comment: somewhat similar issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudspanner-ticketshop-demo/issues/4 , looks like 1604 is deprecated.

Comment: There is more issues the guide beside version of os. Wonder how we can let gg know they should update that doc.

Comment: at the bottom of the page there is a feedback button

Comment: Thank you @danyL.  I submitted a feedback before asking the question here.